# Getting Cast Exception Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm creating a simple note app in android. I am basically using two activity classes named as Main Page and Second Activity. I'm storing some data in the shared preferences in second activity and want to use it in my first Activity. I'm storing data in shared preferences as (String,Integer) key-pair. In my main activity class, when i'm getting the value from shared preferences as Integer and compare it with value 0,i'm getting an exception that java.lang.string can't be cast to java.lang.integer. I don't know why this exception is coming. Android studio is not giving me an exception but when i run my app, my app crashes. I have attach the code for reference.

**MainActivity class:**

```
package com.example.prateeksharma.noteballondor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainPage extends ActionBarActivity {

    Notes notes = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.example.prateeksharma.noteballondor", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //Map<String, Integer> notesMap = (Map<String, Integer>)sharedPreferences.getAll();
        List<Notes> listNotes = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, ?> prefsMap = sharedPreferences.getAll();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: prefsMap.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() == 0){
                notes = new Notes();
            }
            notes.setNoteText(entry.getKey());
            listNotes.add(notes);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(entry.getKey(),2);
        }
        NotesArrayAdapter  notesArrayAdapter = new NotesArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_layout, listNotes);
        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listview.setAdapter(notesArrayAdapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
/**/
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                notes = (Notes) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Notes",notes);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.new_link:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Notes",(android.os.Parcelable)null);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
}
```

**SecondActivity Class:**

```
package com.example.prateeksharma.noteballondor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    Notes notes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.example.prateeksharma.noteballondor", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        notes = (Notes)intent.getParcelableExtra("Notes");
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        if(notes != null){
            editText.setText(notes.getNoteText());
        }
        else{
            editText.setText(null);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getIntent().removeExtra(notes.getNoteText());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.save:
                EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                if (notes != null){
                    edit.putInt(String.valueOf(editText.getText()),1);
                }
                else{
                    edit.putInt(String.valueOf(editText.getText()),0);
                }
                edit.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.delete:
                if(notes != null){
                    edit.remove(notes.getNoteText());
                    edit.commit();
                    finish();
                    return true;
                }

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes class that I'm using:**

```
package com.example.prateeksharma.noteballondor;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * Created by Dell on 02-06-2015.
 */
    public class Notes implements Parcelable {

        private String noteText;

        public String getNoteText() {
            return noteText;
        }

        public void setNoteText(String noteText) {
            this.noteText = noteText;
        }


        private Notes(Parcel in) {
            noteText = in.readString();
        }

        public Notes(){

        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(noteText);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<Notes> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Notes>() {
            @Override
            public Notes createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Notes(in);
            }

            @Override
            public Notes[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Notes[size];
            }
        };
    }
```

Can anybody tell me why this error is coming in MainActivity class at this line
                if (entry.getValue() == 0)

Thank you..

Comment: It could be that when you define `Map<String, ?> prefsMap = sharedPreferences.getAll();` you're including all of the values stored in your SharedPreferences, which includes the `noteText` Strings you're saving in your `onOptionsItemSelected` method, which would definitely cause a ClassCastException since you're attempting to cast every single item stored in your prefs as an Integer.

Comment: @Guardians Sorry..but I could not understand your answer. In  second Activity class onOptionsItemSelected method, i'm storing Key-pair value as (String,Integer) in sharedPreferences.. So value should always be integer. I'm using putInt method of sharedPreferece class. In the Main Activity class, I'm doing Map.get(Key) to get the value which should always be integer. Can u please elaborate ur answer or correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
if ((Integer)entry.getValue() == 0){
```

With

```
If((Integer.parseInt( entry.getValue()) ==0){
```

Comment: Nilesh entry.getvalue() is an integer value and i can'y use Integer.parseInt() on integer parameter. I have also edited my question to remove integer cast as there is no need of it.